# Use Arrow Function in Class Method to access Class Property

Tags: javascript, typescript

I've put together a simplified example of what I'm trying to do, obviously a bit contrived... I have this class:

```
export class myClass {

    a = 'bar';
    b = 0;

    save(x: any = null): void {
        //save all properties
        //...
    }
}
```

In other classes that need to use it, I will define `foo = new myClass();`

Then it can be used either as:

```
this.foo.b = 3
this.foo.save();
```

or, because sometimes I just want it on one line (hence the `x: any = null`:

```
this.foo.save(this.foo.b = 3);
```

I would like to write the single line version more elegantly, and feel something like this should be possible... is it?

```
//How can I make this possible?
this.foo.save(c => c.b = 3)
```

if it is possible, what would the add method look like?

Many thanks!

Comment: Why would you want to write it in one line? Code readability is more important than the number of lines of code you write.

Comment: As this seems to be about some personal feeling on code style, rather than a problem, here is my opinion: I raised my eyebrows irl when i saw the combination of `add(x: any = null)` to allow for this abomination of `this.calc.add(this.calc.b = 3);`.

Comment: "*//How can I make this possible? this.calc.add(c => c.b = 3)*" you can but I'd argue you shouldn't. You're sacrificing the design of your interface for *very slight* convenience when typing. If you need, you can make a new method like `addAndSetB(n: number)`  which, while not great, is at least *better*.

Comment: It would be helpful to describe your actual problem rather than a pointless example.

Comment: Also viable - make a fluent interface and write `this.calc.setB(3).add()` or similar.

Comment: Or just use a getter for `sum`

Comment: Thanks all :)  I agree this is my preference, but I think the 3rd line is the easiest to read (if it were possible).  The 'real' add() function saves to localStorage, so has no return, and I'd like to keep the list of properties flexible, so setB() is more code than I'd like in the class...

Comment: I mean what is wrong with the stereotypical version of `class Calculator { a = 10; b = 0; get sum(){ return this.a + this.b; } }`?

Comment: @BenRobinson "*I think the 3rd line is the easiest to read*" it's not clear whether the callback would be executed *before* or *after* the `.add()` operation. So just by looking at the line, assuming we know `a=2`, `b=0`, it's impossible to guess whether `.add(c => c.b = 3)` would produce `2` or `5` as `sum`.

Comment: The actual works of `add()` are not relevant, just so long as b gets set to 3 before add() runs; I should have called it `.save()` to avoid that confusion!

Comment: I've edited the example code to make my intentions a little clearer :)

Comment: OK, in this case,it's not clear whether the callback would be executed *before* or *after* the .add() operation. So just by looking at the line, assuming we know a=2, b=0, it's impossible to guess whether .add(c => c.b = 3) would save `b` as `0` or `3`.

Comment: Agreed, but the previous two examples show the goal of how it should work; b needs to be set to 3 before the function runs...

Comment: "*but the previous two examples show the goal of how it should work;*" again, that's only *reading the line you proposed*. If you only have that one line, you don't have the previous two examples at your disposal. You have that one line. And unless you're very familiar with the implementation, it's non-intuitive how it works. I see no benefit of *not* having a separate mechanism to set `b` before the `save` operation. Your proposal makes consuming this API unclear, sloppy, and error prone. All for actually no improvement, since the amount of code you write is the same anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Answer for the [original question](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/69390390/1).

If you want `this.calc.add(c => c.b = 3)`, then you need to handle invoking the function `c => c.b = 3` once passed to the add method.

So just check the value is a function, if it is then pass `this` to the function, which would be `c` in your function, then the return value you add with `this.b`

Plain old js.

```js
class Calculator {
  constructor() {
    this.a = 10
    this.b = 0
    this.sum = 0
  }
  add(x) {
    this.sum = this.a + (typeof x === 'function' ? x(this) : x)
  }
}

const calc = new Calculator()

calc.add(c => c.b = 3)
console.log(calc.sum)

calc.add(1)
console.log(calc.sum)
```

Comment: Thanks for this; good answer; I've just had a play with it and see that b gets set after add is run (in fact b seems unused in reality...) so doesn't quite work for what I'm doing.

Comment: np, add is called before, if you want c.b = 3 set first your need to change it to `calc.add(c => calc.b = 3)`, then it makes `c` and the whole use of the function redundant, why not just do `calc.add(calc.b = 3)`

Comment: though since the question has changed, I don't think the Calculator is what your using anyway ;p

Comment: But then were just back to `this.calc.add(this.calc.b = 3);` :D

Comment: This example might help https://playcode.io/817299/ im thinking you might be after a *hidden* thing on the object which then when you hit .save the method knows about it but when you output its not shown, i.e Object.defineProperty, dunno..

Answer (score -1):

Implicitly assigning is anti pattern

```
// Something that you should avoid
this.calc.b = 3
```

```
class Calc {
    constructor(private a: number = 0, private b: number = 0) {}

    setA(a: number) {
        this.a = a;
        return this;
    }

    setB(b: number) {
        this.b = b;
        return this;
    }

    sum() {
        return this.a + this.b;
    }
}

const calc = new Calc();

// will return 0
console.log(calc.sum()); 

// will return 6
console.log(calc.setA(1).setB(5).sum());


const calc1 = new Calc(1,2);

// will return 3
console.log(calc1.sum());
```

Comment: "*Implicitly assigning is anti pattern*" 1. This is definitely not an implicit assignment. It's explicit. 2. It's not an anti-pattern. Depends on how you want to design your API.

Comment: Thanks for you answer, but sadly doesn't work as I'm not actually building a calculator, `add()` should have been called `save()` as I don't want anything back from the function, it will just save in the background; also `a` and `b` are examples, this list of properties is flexible, and having a function for each will make it less flexible :(